# How do I study the domain of a Cauchy's problem without solving it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

I have some problems that require to study the domain of the Cauchy's problem solution but I don't really know how to do that. For example,

$\begin{cases}
y'=(y-\sin x)^2+1+\cos x\\
y(0)=0
\end{cases}$

I did few theorems about Cauchy's problem but none of them says where the solution is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $u=y-\sin x$, the the ODE reduces to
$$
u'=u^2+1.
$$
This has an easy solution via separation of variables with the then obvious maximal domain.

For problems where such easy solutions are not possible, see for instance

- [Existence of solution $y(x)$ with $x \in [0,\frac12]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2986052/115115)
- [Riccati D.E., vertical asymptotes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2348022/115115)
- [Prove that the IVP $\begin{cases}\dot{x}=x^3+e^{-t^2}\\x(0)=1\end{cases}$ has an unique solution defined on $I=(-1/9,1/9)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2622702/115115)

Comment: Ok, thank you.. I don't think my course is that advance but still interesting.